# Using #using <System.dll> with precompiled headers in C++

Tags: c++, .net, using, precompiled-headers

Is here any possibility to use

```
#using <System.dll>
```

with precompiled headers in visual studio 2005 in C++? Now I am gettin g error:

`Error 10 fatal error C1190: managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option`

Comment: The error is not about precompiled headers!

Answer (score 0):

Error message tells you everything. To enable this directive you need to enable `Common Language Runtime Support` - you can find this option in properties of your project.

Also [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s(v=vs.80).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab9swk4(v=vs.80).aspx)